# Oracle Cloud Performance (HCM) )module, it does have the standard process for Ratings against Goals.Can we capture Promotion recommendations too?

Tags: oracle-cloud-functions

We need to capture the Promotion recommendation also as part of the performance appraisal so accordingly the C&B & Role change can also be captured.

Need a way to capture the Promotion recommendation also at this stage.